# Case statement to check if a column has 1-100 as values

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a column which signifies the percentage of amount to be chosen. But due to bad data I have decimal values(amount) in the same column. How can I write case in order to choose only the numbers(1-100). If it's number from ,1-100 I can proceed by calculating the percentage with balance.

```
Ass-cd Ass-valu balance
P.      10.      3456
P.      300.23.  10000
A.      200.     800
P.      1.       6000
```

Balance is available in another table which I will join.

The result should be x% from `balance` or X amount from `balance`.

If `Ass-cd` is **P** I should take only 1-100 numbers for further calculation as it percentage. But due to bad data have decimal values in that.

Comment: Check `MOD(amount, 1) = 0`

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images). [mcve]

Comment: You want to retrieve rows from the database table where the [amount?] column contains whole numbers between 1 (one) and 100 (one hundred). Is that correct?

Comment: @Abra No there  column  A which specifies if column B is percentage or Amount. But even when column A says it's percentage, I m having amount values in column B instead of percentage.

Comment: So you want the table rows where column `A` indicates **percent** and column `B` contains a whole number between 1 and 100. Is that correct?

Comment: @Abra have added sample values in the question. 1 is indicator if it percentage or Amount.  Another is value for 1st column.

Comment: @dnoeth No that doesn't work.

Comment: Third time lucky? If `Ass-cd` equals **P** then you want rows where `balance` is between 1 and 100. And if `Ass-cd` is ___not___ **P** then you want `balance`, whatever value it contains. Did I get it right this time?

Comment: Answer from @Littlefoot should work or are you looking for something else ?

Comment:  @Abra if P I want values of  ass_val to be between 1-100. based on which I can calculate balance column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can use 
select case when MOD(amount, 1) = 0 then amount else 0 end as amount from <table Name> where amount != 0;
```

This will filter out the decimal records.Further you can apply percentage also accordginly in same sql.

Comment: Mod (33436.7,1) returns 0.7 how can I use this. I simply want to avoid those column. Wen I calculate the balance based on % these records will be issue. So asking if we can use case where we pick only if it's 1-100 for that column

Comment: agree that Mod (33436.7,1) returns 0.7 , but the case statement will filter out those records which are set as ZERO , all decimal values .

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you'd check

```
where amount = trunc(amount)
  and trunc(amount) between 1 and 100
```

which means that rows with decimal numbers in the `amount` column would be skipped.

Comment: Trunc of 3243.45 gives 3243. I want to consider only numbers from 1-100 which specifies percentage

Comment: Aha; I thought that values already *ARE* in that range, but some of them are decimals. So - add another condition (see edited example).

Comment: If `amount` equals `trunc(amount)`, why do you need to check whether `trunc(amount)` is between 1 and 100? Shouldn't the second criteria be: `and amount between 1 and 100`?

Comment: Because, @Abra - as far as I understood - amount can be e.g. 10.23 and that shouldn't be used.

Comment: Wat if I have value 100.20 , that will also be picked.it should not pick any value other than 1-100

Comment: It will be rejected because - for 100.20 - AMOUNT isn't equal to TRUNC(AMOUNT), and because AMOUNT isn't between 1 AND 100, so none of conditions is met.